# Database table is not created using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to create a table using PHP, it's not created. But when I try to execute same code in MySQL, it works perfectly.

Here is my code.

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE docs_1 (  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  leadid text NOT NULL,  filename text NOT NULL,  title text NOT NULL)";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` will show you any errors mysql encounters.

Comment: Is this the only bit of code that you are executing? Where is the dsn connection? Are you even opening the connection to mysql?

Comment: Do this instead => `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and debug it yourself.

Comment: You should also use mysqli instead of the mysql extension, since mysql is deprecated in newer PHP version. (as of 5.3 if I am correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your *query* itself.

- The reason may very well be the MySQL library you are using which may be deprecated. Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will tell you if it is.
- Another possible reason could be that you haven't successfully connected to your database. That information hasn't been included in your original post.

Use this `mysqli_` method which was tested successfully:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$DB_HOST = 'xxx'; // Replace
$DB_USER = 'xxx'; // with
$DB_PASS = 'xxx'; // your
$DB_NAME = 'xxx'; // own


$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE docs_1
(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  
leadid text NOT NULL,  
filename text NOT NULL,  
title text NOT NULL)";


$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if(!$result) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }

    else {

        echo "Successful query.";

    }

?>
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thanks. Converting to mysqli helped me.

Comment: @user3752006 You're very much welcome, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: Thanks. Added error reporting in file is rather convenient, instead changeing my.ini file MAMP everytime you need it.

Answer (score 0):

*It's because `date` is a predefinied word in MySQL, and you can't use it as a colum's name.*

**EDIT:**
Sry,  Fred -ii- has right, it isn't a predefined word, so my answer isn't relevant

Comment: it gives me error like this:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"date" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,' at line 1

Comment: If you want to do this, you need to use backticks, not quotes. Though I'd recommend avoiding using reserved words for column and table names if at all possible - it will save you headaches in the future.

Comment: *"It's because date is a predefinied word in MySQL, and you can't use it as a colum's name."* - I beg to differ; I've used it many times. As for *predefined*, I hope you're not talking about it being a MySQL reserved word, because it isn't. Here, read up http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html - It's definitely the OP's syntax.